# Do In Background error In Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I try to view member list.But the following error is displayed.I have attached a video link. in video there is a list of registered user id.these email id stored in php admin successfully. I want when I click on view group then the list user Id will displayed. please check link then code and tell where I am wrong.

Link: http://screencast.com/t/VAfUaUa8MS

Viewgroup.java

```
private class ViewMembers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {

            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(viewgroup.this);
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {
                        JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                         job.put("status_key","0");
                         job.put("method","group_details");
                         job.put("login_token",login_token);

                      StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/DGCapp/webservice.php");

                      httppost.setEntity(se);
                      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                      JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                      Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                        JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("all_group_emails");  
                          for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("please print my name...for....");
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                emailArray.add(jsob.getString("email_id").toString());
                              System.out.print("email array is: "+ emailArray);

                                 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(viewgroup.this, R.layout.listrow, emailArray);          
                          } catch (JSONException e) {

                          }
                    }}

                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(viewgroup.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                    alert.setMessage("No Internet connection ");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) 
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();


                        }
                    });
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            //pDialog.dismiss();
                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return params;

            }             

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
            {

                super.onPostExecute(result);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
            }
            }         
       }
```

Logcat.

```
07-16 02:48:36.093: W/System.err(906): org.json.JSONException: No value for all_group_emails
07-16 02:48:36.093: W/System.err(906):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
07-16 02:48:36.093: W/System.err(906):  at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
07-16 02:48:36.103: W/System.err(906):  at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.viewgroup$ViewMembers.doInBackground(viewgroup.java:86)
07-16 02:48:36.103: W/System.err(906):  at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.viewgroup$ViewMembers.doInBackground(viewgroup.java:1)
07-16 02:48:36.103: W/System.err(906):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
```

PHP services

```
function group_details($data)
{
    $user_id = NULL;

    if ($user_id = getUser($data -> login_token))
    {
        $msg = array();
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM `add_emails_mygroup` WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
        if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
        {
            while($get = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                $msg[] = $get;
            }
            return array("all_group_emails" => $msg, "err-code" => "0");
        }
        else
        {
            return array("message" => "No Data has been Found.", "err-code" => "410");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return array("err-code"=>"1","data"=>"Session Expired");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your json data?

Comment: You're looking for "all_group_emails" in the JSON.  That field doesn't exist.  Either remove that request, use the optional get function, fix your json so it has it, or fix your parser so it looks in the right spot for it.

Comment: There's no array with `all_group_emails`. Check your json response once or post here